# Linq to entities TPC and eager loading child class relationship

Tags: linq-to-entities, table-per-class

Thank you for your thoughts

I am using entity framework 5.0, model first.

a table is mapped using a table per class (or table per concrete type) pattern.

Table A 1..Many (Abstract) Table B

Table B has 2 child classes

B1 & B2

B2 has a foreign key to a 3rd table, let's say Table C (Many B2 ... 1 C), but this is not a property of the parent class B.

Eager loading is the default for the application, and I want to include Table (or collection) C when querying on table B2 - the equivalent of (pseudo linq to entities):

```
from A in _db.A
.Include(A=>A.B.OfType<B2>())
.Include(A=>A.B.OfType<B2>().Include(C))
select A
```

thanks for any thoughts for how I can force an eager load of this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that `Include(A=>A.B.OfType<B2>())` is not supported.

As far as I understand the ADO.Net team it seems that they don't want to support partially loaded child collections. (And I tend to agree with them.) In Linq-to-sql there were [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx), but there is no EF equivalent of them. That could explain why `Include` with `OfType` is not supported either, because it would tell EF to partly load the collection of `B`s.

Moreover, the extension method [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is only a wrapper around the Include method (if present) of an `IQueryable` objects itself. 
Take [`ObjectQuery.Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx): a pretty simple method with just a string as parameter (Same for `DbQuery.Include`) that contains the path to the navigation property to be included (`_db.A.Include("B")`). In other words: you can only only use strings that can be resolved to a MemberExpression. And `B.OfType<>()` is a method.

Long story to explain why you can't include `C`: the path leading to `C` is not valid.

You *could* do

```
_db.B.OfType<B2>().Include(b => b.A).Include(b => b.C)
```

But that may not give you the results you were after.

Comment: Thank you - a well thought out answer, and a definitive no saves hours of trying to work around a problem. TPC inheritance was used to reuse a lot of commonality in associated partial classes, but the inability to use the include OfType makes me think I should have implemented interfaces and extension methods instead.